# Ubuntu(Or any other linux distro) stuck on retrieving clocksource

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, installation, bios

The past few days I have been trying to install linux on my laptop(Asus UX430) with no luck. I have tried elementaryOs,PopOS,Manjaro,Ubuntu,Kubuntu,Gentoo and Fedora but they all gave me the same error:
[image: my problem]

The things that I already have tried:

1. Using different kernelparameters like `noapic` `clocksource=...` `nomodeset` `compress=gzip`
2. Changing My BIOS(SATA is already set to AHCI, Secure boot and fast boot are disabled and I turned of everything that could be a problem(fingerprint scan etc).
3. Booting in safe mode, or live mode(same error).
4. Trying GRUB parameters like setting resolution, compression algorithms.
5. Upgrading BIOS
6. Using older versions of ubuntu
7. Waited for an hour
8. Used kernel parameters specific to my notebook model documented on the ubuntu wiki.

I have no clue what to do given that I have the feeling I tried all provided solutions on ubuntu forums and stack overflow. Is there any way to fix this? If you need more info just tell me.

EDIT: If I remove my USB while booting, it does detect it in verbose mode. Maybe this indicated that is not totally frozen because interrupts work but just "stuck" somewhere, because waiting for an hour doesnt make it boot.

Comment: Hardware problem, or obscure hardware?  -> https://www.google.com/search?q=clocksource+linux

Comment: If your BIOS has a diagnostics option, I would run that. Also, I hate to say it, but trying to install Windows might give additional information.

Comment: (1) How long have you waited for the boot? Try waiting for at least 10 minutes. (2) A similar [bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1886249) was fixed in Fedora 33, so you could try it. (3) Setting this grub boot parameter might help: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="tpm_tis.force=1"`.

Comment: @harrymc I tried the boot paramater and waited an hour, no luck, same error. :(

Comment: Did you also try a Fedora distribution?

Comment: @harrymc Yes, same problem.

Comment: @bitinerant I already have installed windows(works fine), I want to boot into live cd so I can overwrite windows and make it a full linux machine.

Comment: Try all the grub boot parameters for clocksource mentioned in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/380960/8672) (one by one).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117848/discussion-between-jurriaan-buitenweg-and-harrymc).